# not sure how to model in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am making a simple event system (like physical events, not software events). It has the following structure. Each event will have a set of slots (think a music event, opening act, healiner etc...). Each event_slot will be a reference to a tag. Right now I have the following but I think this is not going to work:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #id primary key
  has_many :event_slots, :order => "sort desc" 
  has_many :tags, :through => :event_slots 
end

# event_slots will be populuated with tag_id
class EventSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  # event_id, tag_id; will also have a sort value to sort these
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

the issue is that event_slots will have a tag_id. In other words we'll be adding the tags and associating them in place (like physically in place in a web form).

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_slots
end
```

I am not sure if this modeling will work. Any ideas on how to implement / improve this this? The has_many :through seems not be done correctly.

thx

Comment: you need to provide a bit more info about what you're trying to achieve. What are EventSlots and why do you need to model these, what fields are stored under an eventslot?

Comment: it seems pretty straightforward in terms of what is trying to be achieved

Comment: Not really. What do you mean by "associating them in place"?

Comment: tag's would be populated before or created via a jquery form - from a modeling pov, the tag_id would be in the event_slot

Comment: I agree.  I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: A few comments about what you a trying to achieve from a users perspective would help a lot. Whether your using jquery etc doesnt really matter what we need to know is what you are trying to model. What are EventSlots? And why do you need them?

Comment: i updated. multiple slots for different even piece. I agree about the jquery mention - not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work fine. I would perhaps try use a better name than EventSlots because its not intuitive what it represents. If its aimed at the music market something like Acts would perhaps make more sense.

Using something like accepts_nested_attributes_for on the Event model can help eliminate the need for a controller for the second nested model (Act/EventSlot). Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 if you havent already.

Lastly I would consider not rolling your own tagging system. There are already plenty of well tested gems you can use to provide the functionality you need. Check out https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging.html to find one that might suit your needs.

Comment: thx for looking - I looked at some of the tagging systems and they seemed to have too many bugs to inlcude. Possibly, I might create a second system that feeds into a prebuilt tagging system so that if I don't like it, I can swap it out and put a new one in. Push it as far out as possible